# Forem Groups have badges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, forem

I am trying to accomplish a system where I can put users into a group named "Moderator" and they would get a bootstrap badge with the text moderator and the color specified in the groups panel.

Then lets say I put the members in a Donor group and they would get the badge as well. I also plan to have their usernames colored by the highest priority group (priority set in groups panel) and it would give them that color in post view and in the topics view.

I am not asking for this to be implemented just trying to figure out how to do it myself.

Comment: You might want to try working out your ideas and, when you have a specific problem, *then* try posting the question here on SO :)  Welcome to SO, by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups  # a user can be associated to a group that doesn't have a corresponding badge
    has_many :badges  # the association to a group through a badge is also possible but due to business constraints, this may not neccessarily be so
  end`

class Badge < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
  end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users;
  end